# Rails STI not saving "type" field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I'm trying to set up a single table inheritance for Questions table. I've followed some advices adding a route this way :

> resources :vfquestions,     :controller => 'questions', :type =>
>   'Vfquestion'

And the model :

```
class Vfquestion < Question
end
```

It works, saving the question in the database, but the `type` field stays empty.

Here is my controller :

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @questions = @user.questions.where(:type => params[:type])
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @question = @category.questions.new
    @question.type = params[:type]
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @category = @user.categories.find(params[:category_id])
    @question = @category.questions.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @question = @category.questions.new(question_params)
    @question.user_id = current_user.id
    @question.save
  end

  private
    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body)
    end

end
```

Am I missing something to save this param ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `type` is not saved for the base class. It also can't be overridden via params, as that would mean `X.new` would potentially yield an instance of a class other than `X`.

What you need to do is create the correct type on the way in:

```
@question =
  case (params[:question][:type])
  when 'Vfquestion'
    Vfquestion.new(params[:question])
  else
    Question.new(params[:question])
  end

@category.questions << @question
```

The relationship is also defined in terms of a singular base class, so all objects built in that scope will default to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing in your `Category` model you have a line:

```
has_many :questions
```

The problem is that this relationship is pointing to the parent `Question` model; it has no idea you want to create or find any of its subtypes (Remember that Rails operates on convention over configuration; in this case, rails is locating your `Question` model because of the convention for naming `has_many` relationships).

One way to solve this is add the appropriate subtypes like so:

```
has_many :vfquestions
has_many :some_other_question_subtype
```

And then to create, for example, a new `VFQuestion` for a particular category, you would simply do:

```
@question = @category.vfquestions.new(question_params)
```

**Side Note**

Part of the problem in your situation is, in your `create` method, you have no way of distinguishing between a `VFquestion`, or some other question sub type when you go to create it. You'll have to figure out the best way to handle this for your particular domain, but possibly the simplest way to handle this is to pass a `type` parameter from the form. So, for example, if you have some kind of radio button that flops between the different question types, make sure it is named appropriately to it is sent when the form is submitted. Then simply check that piece of data in the params and either invoke `.vfquestions`, or some other question sub type.